# C++ Sorting array of const pointers to structs

Tags: c++, sorting, constants, counting-sort

I have sorting function:

```
void countingSort(TPhone * const * array, int count) {

    // some code

    // making copy od array
    TPhone * const * arrayCopy = new TPhone * [count];

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        arrayCopy[i] = array[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int index = // some function to determine where to place array[i]
        array[index] = arrayCopy[i];
    }
}
```

I ommited details about the sorting algorithm because the problem is somewhere else. Thing is, there's problem with declaration of the `arrayCopy`.

on lines

```
arrayCopy[i] = array[i]
...
array[index] = arrayCopy[i];
```

i get this error messages

```
error: assignment of read-only location ‘*(arrayCopy + ((sizetype)(((long unsigned int)i) * 8ul)))’
error: assignment of read-only location ‘*(array + ((sizetype)(((long unsigned int)index) * 8ul)))’
```

There must be something wrong with `const` usage in declaration but I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: Why are you using const at all? When you declare something as constant you are telling the compiler that you don't intend to modify it.

Comment: Probably copied the type declaration of the parameter.  Change `TPhone* const*` to `TPhone*` (or even `auto`).

Comment: @RedAlert I don't understand your point. The pointers *in* the pointer array can certainly be pointers-to-const. They're objects to which they point are not (and should not) be modified here. Its the pointer array *content*, not what that content points to, that is being changed. So the OP telling the compiler "this is a modifiable pointer array of pointers-to-const objects seems more than reasonable. They're doing it *wrong* (duh), but the idea is sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read const and pointer declarations from right to left:

```
TPhone * const * arrayCopy
   ^   ^   ^   ^    ^
   |   |   |   |    \---- arrayCopy is a 
   |   |   |   \------------ pointer to
   |   |   \------------------- const
   |   \-------------------------- pointer to
   \--------------------------------- TPhone
```

So, arrayCopy is effectively an array of constant pointers (and so is array).  Constant pointers cannot be moved (i.e. you cannot change *where* they point).  Thus, you cannot overwrite them, and thus, you cannot sort them.

If you wanted an array of pointers to constant TPhone (i.e., you cannot change the fields of TPhone, but you can move pointers around), then you should move the const:

```
pointer to constant TPhone:
TPhone const *   // right-to-left

array of pointer to constant TPhone:
TPhone const * []   // right-to-left
but since arrays can't easily be passed to functions, you can use a pointer:
TPhone const * *   // right-to-left
```

Then you can change the *pointers* (which are just memory addresses), but you cannot change the actual TPhone objects.